# Positioning of h2 tags are messed up after a certain view width/window's width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the positioning of my "rightside" navigation.
The problem is that when the viewport width is 767px and below, the `h2`s of the rightnav will move directly right next to the `#leftnav`. What I want to happen is that it'll still stick to the right almost the edge of the screen. The same thing happens when I remove the `h2` tags and use a menu button instead.

The code is below, and I included links to 2 pictures to show what I'm talking about.

---

More than 767px:
[image: Screenshot > 767px]

767px and below:
[image: Screenshot <= 767px]

---

HTML:

```
<header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav id="leftnav" class="col-sm-4 text-left">
            <h1 id="myname"><a href="#">Ali</a></h1>
        </nav>

        <nav id="rightnav" class="col-sm-8 text-right">
            <h2 id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
            <h2 id="aboutme"><a href="#">About Me</a></h2>
            <h2 id="myservices"><a href="#">My Services</a></h2>
            <h2 id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></h2>
            <h2 id="blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></h2>
            <h2 id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
header .row {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px black;
}
#leftnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
#myname {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
#myname a {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif, "Arial";
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
#rightnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#rightnav h2 {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif, "Arial";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.72vw;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: You should consider accepting which solution worked best for you by checking the green mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your HTML and had to make some assumptions about the structure. Firstly, I assume you are using Bootstrap since your classes are using that namespace, so I used Bootstrap v4. Secondly, my further assumptions are in removing a `</div>` tag and adding a `<header>` tag to make the HTML valid. Your fixed code is below, and the link content sticks to the right side, which was your stated goal.

The problems I found:

- There was no ending `<header>` tag.
- Extra ending `</div>` tag next to ending half of HTML comment `-->` code; I removed both of these.

I had to improvise from your image and insert (among other things) a link for the Bootstrap CSS. I had to assume the version of Bootstrap you used.

```css
header .row {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px black;
}

#leftnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#myname {
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

#myname a {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif, "Arial";
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

#rightnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#rightnav h2 {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif, "Arial";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.72vw;
color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav id="leftnav" class="col-sm-4 text-left">
          <h1 id="myname"><a href="#">Ali</a></h1>
        </nav>
        <nav id="rightnav" class="col-sm-8 text-right">
          <h2 id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
          <h2 id="aboutme"><a href="#">About Me</a></h2>
          <h2 id="myservices"><a href="#">My Services</a></h2>
          <h2 id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></h2>
          <h2 id="blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></h2>
          <h2 id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jeez, I didn't realise the that the header had no ending tag. 
Thank you for the help and the two links, I'll definitely refer to it!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are trying for HTML5 compliance and not seeing valid HTML, the following was pasted into the W3C HTML validator ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav id="leftnav" class="col-sm-4 text-left">
            <h1 id="myname"><a href="#">Ali</a></h1>
        </nav>  
        <nav id="rightnav" class="col-sm-8 text-right">
            </div>
        <h2 id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
        <h2 id="aboutme"><a href="#">About Me</a></h2>
        <h2 id="myservices"><a href="#">My Services</a></h2>
        <h2 id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></h2>
        <h2 id="blog"><a href="#">Blog</a></h2>
        <h2 id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following errors appeared.

- Error: End tag div seen, but there were open elements. From line 14, column 9; to line 14, column 14 > ↩
- Error: Unclosed element nav. From line 13, column 5; to line 13, column 51
  av>
- Error: Stray end tag nav. From line 21, column 5; to line 21, column 10

  Error: Stray end tag div. From line 22, column 1; to line 22, column 6

  Error: End tag for  body seen, but there were unclosed elements. From line 23, column 1; to line 23, column 7 v>

  Error: Unclosed element header. From line 8, column 1; to line 8, column 32 d>

You have to have valid HTML before anyone can answer questions regarding the CSS with any surety.  In fact, your CSS may work fine if your HTML is valid.  The only reason it renders at all is because browsers are horribly (and dysfunctionally) permissive.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.

I was in a rush, didn't realise that I had a couple of useless tags and unclosed tags.

Comment: It is if you include Bootstrap, which is what those CSS classes are from.